# explain the following Perl Code?

Tags: perl

Can anybody explain the following Perl code for me, please?
I think its in Perl and I have no clue about Perl programming. Please explain what the following code does?

```
$t = test(10);
sub test() {
  my $str = unpack("B32", pack("N",shift));
  $str2 = substr($str,16,length($str));
  return $str2;
}
```

Comment: `sub test { sprintf('%016X', shift & 0xFFFF) }` might be clearer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pack, unpack and substr functions are documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html), respectively.

`pack("N"...)` packs a number into a four-byte network-order representation. `unpack("B32"...)` unpacks this packed number as a string of bits (zeros and ones). The `substr` call takes the second half of this bit string (from bit 16 onwards), which represents the lower 16 bits of the original 32-bit number.

Why it does it this way is a mystery to me. A simpler and faster solution is to deal with the lower 16 bits at the outset (note the lower case `"n"`):

```
sub test($) {
  return unpack("B16", pack("n",shift));
}
```

Comment: Or the potentially less confusing `return sprintf "%016b", shift & 0xffff` which uses operators that you can find in other languages :)

Comment: @hobbs: Good point! You should present it as an answer. Though you'll need parentheses around or after the `shift`.

Answer (score 3):

```
shift
```

pops the first argument to the function from the list of arguments passed

```
pack("N", shift)
```

returns a 32bit network byte order representation of that value

```
my $str = unpack("B32", pack("N", shift));
```

stores a bitstring representation (32 bits worth) of said value (i.e. a string that looks like "00010011").

The `substr` is buggy and should be `substr($str, 16);` to get the last 16 characters of the above. (or `substr($str, 16, 16);`.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marcelo's answer, the `shift` function takes the `@_` as its default argument.  `@_` contains the subroutine's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`pack("N", shift)` takes the argument of the function (return value of shift, which works on the arguments array by default) and makes it into an integer. The `unpack("B32,` part then makes it into string again, of 32 bits, so a string of 0's and 1's. The `substr` just takes the last 16 bit-characters, in this case.