# C# equivalence of Perl's unpack("B32", pack("N", $arg));

Tags: c#

I need help finding the 32-bit binary representation of an integer in C#. In Perl, I'm using `unpack("B32", pack("N", $arg))`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the unpack do? and also what kind of data does it expect?

Comment: The Perl code could have been written `sprintf('%032b', $arg)`

Comment: @ikegami Does your code always force big endian, like the pack `N` parameter does?  I don't know perl, so I am just curious here.

Comment: I feel like this can be done with some String.Format magic

Comment: @John Koerner, The question makes no sense as asked. Write down one hundred twenty-three in decimal or in binary. Did you force big-endianness? Well, whatever your answer is, it's the same as the answer to your question. In the meantime, I'll just restate that they produce the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int x = some_value;
var networkOrder = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(x);
var result = Convert.ToString(networkOrder, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
```

For details please refer to [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6321802/490018).